# abi.encode() giving different results in ganache and sepolia , both of them don't make sense

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache, evm

Steps to reproduce -

1. Deploy to Ganache and sepolia the following contract -

```
contract ABIExample {
    
    event EncodedData(bytes encodedData);

    function encodeAndDecode(uint a, uint[] memory b, bytes memory c) public  returns (uint, uint[] memory, bytes memory) {
        // abi.encode example
        bytes memory encodedData = abi.encode(a, b, c);
        emit EncodedData(encodedData);
        
        // abi.decode example
        (uint decodedA, uint[] memory decodedB, bytes memory decodedC) = abi.decode(encodedData, (uint, uint[], bytes));
        
        return (decodedA, decodedB, decodedC);
        //return (a,b,c)
    }

    function encodePackedExample(uint a, uint b) public  returns (bytes memory) {
        // abi.encodePacked example types shorter than 32 bytes are concatenated directly, without padding or sign extension
        bytes memory packedData = abi.encodePacked(a, b);
        emit EncodedData(packedData);
        
        return packedData;
    }

    function encodeWithSelectorExample(uint a, uint b) public  returns (bytes memory) {
        // abi.encodeWithSelector example
        bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256("exampleFunction(uint256,uint256)"));
        bytes memory withSelectorData = abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, a, b);
        emit EncodedData(withSelectorData);
        
        return withSelectorData;
    }

    function encodeCallExample() public  returns (bytes memory) {
        // abi.encodeCall example
        bytes memory callData = abi.encodeCall(this.exampleFunction, (42, 123));
        emit EncodedData(callData);
        
        return callData;
    }

    function exampleFunction(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint) {
        // Example function for abi.encodeCall
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

2. Call `encodeAndDecode(uint a, uint[] memory b, bytes memory c)`  with following parameters `1, [6,8,1,3,5],0xff`.
3. Observe the emitted event

**Sepolia** `EncodedData` event -

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x9bf331503430077a1edd0434c8c79d72a2066cf8#events

**Ganache** `EncodedData` event -

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**What it should be if my understanding is correct**

`<32bytes for uint(1)> <32 bytes representing length of array> <5*32 bytes for array elements> <32bytes for 0xff>`
So-

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005ff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Why am I getting different results for `Ganache` and `Sepolia` . Why are they not matching with my results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sepolia` result (you can check [here](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xfcd4c469730d6302bbfc04eff48da4acbbf29a9eee3dfe50b263acd91df8e318#eventlog)) is the same as your `Ganache` result. The hex version of it (which is similar, but not the same as the one you provided) has some prefixes (for the total length), but still contains the result from `Ganache`.

Here's the breakdown

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 - 1st input
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060 - 2nd input
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000120 - 3rd input

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
ff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Since your 2nd input has a dynamic length, it will be represented as an offset. Here, `60` in hex equals to 96 bytes. Skip 3 lines (3 x 32 bytes) from the beginning and we got `5`, which is the length of the array.

Same for the 3rd input, `120` in hex equals to 288 bytes (9 x 32 bytes). Skip 9 lines and we got the final input.